# Where can I find historical flight stats?

Tags: air-travel, statistics, flight-status

I'm looking for some old flight stats as Flightaware provides me for the last 4 months. However, I'm looking for flights from the past 5 years. Is there any database that is capable of doing so?  For example, I'm interested in KLM1964 on January 5, 2012.

Specifically, statistics including departure/arrival times, and aircraft type.

Comment: Is there a free way to view historical flights that neither depart from nor arrive at a U.S. airport?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com) has information going back several years.  Their level of coverage is generally excellent, although it can vary a little depending on the airline/location.  You will need to create a free account in order to view data more than a few days old.

Specifically for your flight they don't have any specific information, only scheduled information that the flight was from Zurich (ZRH) to Amsterdam (AMS), departing at 7:25 PM and arriving at 9:00PM on an Embraer RJ170/190.

The lack of information could mean that there is a hole in their data, or it could mean that the flight did not fly for some reason (ie, it was canceled).  Checking that same flight for days before and after there is full information available.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Now you mention it, I can remember that I had to take the flight the next day, because the first flight was cancelled due to a huge winterstorm.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your answer that you need an account to see old flight stats.

Comment: The requirement for having an account is already there - last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: [Tried looking up the flight](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightRating/flightRatingByFlight.do?airlineCode=VY&flightNumber=1015&departureAirportCode=BCN&arrivalAirportCode=MAD) — 
28 flights in the history doesn't look like information going back for yers.

Comment: @Gleb They require a paid subscription now, see the duplicate marked.

Answer (score 4):

FlightView.com has great reports on historic flights (I work in sales there). They're the only flight data provider which are selected as consultants to the FAA, so you know you're getting the most accurate data.

Comment: I would downvote this answer because it's not a free way, and in my knowledge, never was, as well as you being affiliated with the source.